# How do I list all the elements of a container?

Tags: excel, applescript

I have been having trouble navigating the object structure of many applications. Referencing applications' respective dictionaries has only made things more confusing.

With properties, this seems to be straightforward for some applications:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  properties of document 1
end tell
```

Despite the dictionary stating that a `document` contains (by inheritance from `workbook`):

> document properties, chart sheets, command bars, custom document properties, named items, pivot caches, sheets, styles, custom views, windows, worksheets, international macro sheets, macro sheets, table styles

Every time I try to access these like so...

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  worksheet 1 of document 1
end tell
```

... I get the error:

> "The object you are trying to access does not exist" number -1728

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links to sites with some sample script.

https://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/applescript/

http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.02/2302AppleScript/index.html

You're missing a `tell` statement for identifying which file/sheet to access, e.g.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell sheet "Sheet1" of workbook 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my secondary question. My main question (which I admittedly muddled a bit in my original post) is about how one would list the elements of the container. How does one figure out how many workbooks exist, or even that workbooks are a contained element in the first place?

Comment: Nevermind about the first part of that. I figured out how to list all every workbook.

I still would like to know how to list all the elements of a container.

Comment: Do you mean every instance of an element? As in, 'sheets of workbook 1' or a list of all the different elements (e.g. what's in the dictionary) or a laundry list of every instance of every different element?

Comment: Ideally both a list of all the different elements (i.e. what's in the dictionary) and a laundry list of every instance of every different element.

Comment: I don't think that applescript will replicate the dictionary automatically. I've seen some situations where you can get a laundry list but I think that depends upon the app's implementation of applescript. If you're serious (as in willing to spend money) you might take a look at Script Debugger, which includes a dictionary explorer. Otherwise, you'd probably have to craft a script which iterates through the elements to construct that list.